# How to get the NSDictionary inside Array

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to get the dictionary inside an array.

The array is like this:

```
[{"CheckPointId":41,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check SOP maintained near all equipments and loads","MId":41,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":42,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check Single line diagram (SLD) is maintained in panel area","MId":42,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":43,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check danger notices are maintained at site","MId":43,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":44,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check Rubber mats are maintained infront of the electrical panels","MId":44,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":45,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check the availibility of HT gloves","MId":45,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":46,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check Treatment of Electric shock board is displayed","MId":46,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":47,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check Total connected load details are displayed","MId":47,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":48,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check LOTO is in practice ","MId":48,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":49,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check for Lightning arrestor installed in terrace","MId":49,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":50,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check APFC is maintaining power factor (0.99 - 1.00)","MId":50,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":51,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check for history cards maintained near equipments","MId":51,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":52,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check checklists are maintained up to date and duely signed by site incharge","MId":52,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":53,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check for earthing provided to equipments","MId":53,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":54,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check for exhaust mechansim in the equipment and load section","MId":54,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":55,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check for fire extinguisher in the equipment area","MId":55,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"}]
```

I used code like this

```
NSString *string = [LoginResult valueForKey:@"text"];

NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *responsearry = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

for(NSDictionary *dict in responsearry) {
    NSLog(@"----dict--%@",dict);
}
```

But It give me only *first value* that is on `0th` index.

Comment: You can parse dictionary like this `for dict in yourArray`{   `dict` is your parsed dict}

Comment: @PiyushRathi But it shows only on value.

Comment: we applied for loop here, this will iterate until last dict in your array.

Comment: your code is correct, just check count of your array. is it having Count 1?

Comment: @PiyushRathi Its count is 10 Object.

Comment: Actually the data shows 15 objects.

Comment: @Muju Post your response here. I have doubt that in response you are getting once dictionary and in that dictionary you getting your array. in in array again dictionary. And in most of the cases response is in form of NSDictionary.

Comment: @GeneCode Actually I am passing an Id webservice according to it its count get change.

Comment: @Muju can you add console logs here, whats printed in console?

Comment: Can you post the whole method where this thing happens. I think the information is not enough for any of us to help u.

Comment: @GeneCode Thank You I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `for` Loop if you want to iterated all `Dict`:

```
    NSArray *yourArray = [{"CheckPointId":41,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check SOP maintained near all equipments and loads","MId":41,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":42,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check Single line diagram (SLD) is maintained in panel area","MId":42,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":43,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check danger notices are maintained at site","MId":43,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":44,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check Rubber mats are maintained infront of the electrical panels","MId":44,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":45,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check the availibility of HT gloves","MId":45,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":46,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check Treatment of Electric shock board is displayed","MId":46,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":47,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check Total connected load details are displayed","MId":47,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":48,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check LOTO is in practice ","MId":48,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":49,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check for Lightning arrestor installed in terrace","MId":49,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":50,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check APFC is maintaining power factor (0.99 - 1.00)","MId":50,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":51,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check for history cards maintained near equipments","MId":51,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":52,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check checklists are maintained up to date and duely signed by site incharge","MId":52,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":53,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check for earthing provided to equipments","MId":53,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":54,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check for exhaust mechansim in the equipment and load section","MId":54,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"},{"CheckPointId":55,"AId":4,"CheckPoint":"Check for fire extinguisher in the equipment area","MId":55,"MethodOfMeasure":"Visual Inspection"}];

     for(NSDictionary *dict in yourArray)
     {
          NSLog(@"----dict--%@",dict);
     }
```

If you want to get `Dictionary` at particular Index:

```
  int index = 1;
  NSDictionary *dict = [yourArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

Comment: I have 10 Object in my array.But when I used your code Dict value print only 5 Key/value pair.Means only one Object.

Comment: @Muju are you using For loop ??

Comment: Yes I am using for loop.

Comment: @Muju NSLog your `responsearry` and `[responsearry count]` and show us the output.

Comment: its count is 15 Object.

Comment: @Muju Please post your response which are you gettting from server.

Answer (score 0):

did you check if your json string is well formed ?
with "\"
like :
{\"user1\":{\"Iden\":4,\"nID\":1},\"user2\":{\"Iden\":5,\"nID\":1}}

Comment: what I meant is that it should be javascript escaped :

Comment: @"[{\"CheckPointId\":41,\"AId\":4,\"CheckPoint\":\"Check SOP maintained near all equipments and loads\",\"MId\":41,\"MethodOfMeasure\":\"Visual Inspection\"},{\"CheckPointId\":42,\"AId\":4,\"CheckPoint\":\"Check Single line diagram (SLD) is maintained in panel area\",\"MId\":42,\"MethodOfMeasure\":\"Visual Inspection\"},{\"CheckPointId\":43,\"AId\":4,\"CheckPoint\":\"Check danger notices are maintained at site\",\"MId\":43,\"MethodOfMeasure\":\"Visual Inspection\"}]"

Comment: I've shorted the json string since there is a limit of chars to comment, but I tried to deserailze the whole string with escaped format and it worked well